# Feign response interceptor using Spring Cloud OpenFeign

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Feign now supports ResponseInterceptor class. Can I somehow implement it using Spring Cloud Feign or I need to use Feign.builder()?

Tried like this in my custom FeignConfig:

```
@Bean
public ClientResponseInterceptor responseInterceptor() {
    return new ClientResponseInterceptor();
}
```

But seems not working. Any ideas how to inject custom ResponseInterceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I dit not succeeded in using the ResponseInterceptor.

But I've found an alternative using the **feign.codec.Decoder**.

In this example, I'm reading the `Content-Language` of every Feign client responses :

```
public class ClientResponseInterceptor implements Decoder {

    private final JacksonDecoder delegate;

    public ClientResponseInterceptor(JacksonDecoder delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException, FeignException {
        String contentLanguageFromFeignResponse;

        Collection<String> contentLanguage = response.headers().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LANGUAGE);
        // Extract this part in another method
        if (contentLanguage != null && !contentLanguage.isEmpty()) {
            Optional<String> attributeOpt = contentLanguage.stream().findFirst();
            if (attributeOpt.isPresent()) {
                contentLanguageFromFeignResponse = attributeOpt.get();
            }
        }

        // Do something with contentLanguageFromFeignResponse

        return delegate.decode(response, type);
    }
}
```

And declaring it in your feign config file :

```
@Bean
public ClientResponseInterceptor responseInterceptor() {
    return new ClientResponseInterceptor(new JacksonDecoder(/*objectMapper*/));
}
```

(You can use another Decoder, JacksonDecoder is just an example)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code to implement ResponseInterceptor for openfeign with spring-boot.

```
import feign.InvocationContext;
import feign.ResponseInterceptor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FeignClientInterceptor implements ResponseInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object aroundDecode(InvocationContext invocationContext) {

        feign.Response response= invocationContext.response();
        feign.Request request=response.request();

        //Do something with request and response        

        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

Dependency used for this example:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: if I add the dependency and try to implenent the interface ResponseInterceptor I get an error because the interface doesn't exists

Comment: Try using spring coud bom instead: <properties>
       
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

Answer (score 0):

you can tried like this to capture the feign response:

```
package com.config;
 
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.utils.EncryptAES;
import feign.FeignException;
import feign.Response;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder;
 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
 
@Configuration 
public class FeignClientResponseInterceptor extends SpringDecoder {
 
    public FeignClientResponseInterceptor(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters) {
        super(messageConverters);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Object decode(final Response response, Type type) throws IOException, FeignException {
        return o;
    }
 
}
```